# How to tell what fraction of element is inside viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to determine what percentage of a DOM element is inside the current viewport ? I want to calculate the ratio of area of element inside viewport and the total area of the element.

Related question: [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: Can you be more specific mate? What are we talking about here? The percentage of a whole element's area?

Comment: Yes, (Area of an element inside viewport) / Total area taken by the element. For example there is a <div> whose height is 10px and width is 10px. So, total area is 100 sq unit. Now, the area of the <div> inside viewport is (height * width) inside viewport.

Answer (score 1):

See [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and [`Window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight).

```
let {top, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    percentVisible = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (window.innerHeight - top) / height));
```

I'm guessing at your use case, but in modern browsers, see [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and its [`intersectionRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/intersectionRatio).